# Fixing SQL Injection With _mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, sql-injection

I just found out that the way I am using _mysql is causing a major SQL Injection problem.

My current code looks like:

```
db = _mysql.connect('', 'user', 'pass', 'db')
query = """SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE thing="{0}" """.format(user_input)
cur.query(query)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it so that it is safe?

I have tried using _mysql.escape_string() but that still returns an SQL syntax error.

Comment: Well... You need to educate yourself. This seems like acceptable source: <http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/guide-to-php-security-ch3.pdf>.

Comment: *SQL Injection Vulnerability* has nothing to do with syntax errors.  Please clarify your exact question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MySQLdb` on its own:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect();
curs = conn.cursor();
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE thing = %s", (user_input));
```

If you want to stick with `_mysql`, use `db.escape_string(user_input)`.

Documentation: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: I decided to just use MongoDB instead.

Answer (score 2):

A nice handy reference is available via [the bobby tables website](http://bobby-tables.com/).

You may also find value in [In this powerpoint reference](http://www.slideshare.net/openpbs/sql-injection-defense-in-python) which shows some examples of sql injection as well as possible ways to mitigate the issue.